# Learning C++. Writing File To Desktop. No Where to be Found

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I am learning C++ and trying to write a program to create a text file on my desktop and write to it.

For some reason, the file is no where to be found on my desktop.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main () {

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop\\test.txt");
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    myfile.close();
    return 0;

}
```

I am using Eclipse to build and compile my code. Is this the reason it's not writing a file to my desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked for me too. I compiled and ran this on ubuntu. Try to run this from command line in Windows and check whether it works then or not.

Comment: I had to run it from the command line in order for it to work. I don't know why it is like this.

Comment: nvm I figured it out. I had to move my minGW path to above my system32 path in the environment variables. Now it works in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Only a para-answer to get OP on the right track to debugging their own code.

File streams don't tell you much unless you ask them. If the stream fails to open, you can still try to read from it. You won't get anything, but you can try. You won't even get an error message unless you ask. OP is not asking, so they have no way to know what happened or if anything happened.

[Check  to ensure the file is open](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/is_open)

```
if myfile.is_open()
{
    cout << "Opened the file, dude."<< endl;`
}
else
{
    perror("Failed to open the file, man.");
}
```

and check the result of the write

```
if(myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n") 
{
    cout << "Wrote to the file. Cool beans, man."<< endl;`
}
else
{
    perror("Failed to write to the file, man.");
}
```

to make sure the data was written.

[The output of `perror` should give you a hint of what went wrong and how to fix it.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/perror)

Comment: In addition to checking for error conditions, you should use ``SHGetFolderPath`` or ``SHGetKnownFolderPath`` to get the desktop path rather than hard-coding it.

Answer (score -1):

Went well for me... Check the MyName part of the path.. It should be your username. I did not use Eclipse, I used Qt.

Comment: If someone vote negative they should explain the reason...